# open url on drop

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, hyperlink

this is a very basic question, because I'm a very basic coder :)

I'm using the drag and drop functionality in HTML5

Everything is fine up to the moment of opening the URL (in the same window)... the images are draggable, the drag and drop works fine. But...

How do I make the browser open a URL associated to an element dropped inside another one, and how do I associate that URL to that element?

To be more clear. In the homepage I have an image gallery. To each image I need to associate a different url (do I simply put it in the id?). Just under the gallery there is a box. When I drag and drop an image in this box, the browser needs to open a specific link.

Thank you!

Giovanni

Comment: If the below answered your question you should accept it

Answer (score 1):

Put your link on your data and load it on the drop event, like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #div1, #div2
            {float:left; width:100px; height:35px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
        </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev)
        {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Url","http://www.google.fr");
        }

        function drop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
            window.location=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Url");
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
         <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31"></div>
        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

put event.preventDefault() in drop function or all drag/drop functions

```
function drop(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    // Code...
}
```